# parsing HashMap into xml with Simple XML - JAVA

Tags: java, xml, parsing, hashmap, simple-framework

I need to put the values inside a pat as the values of my XML file for Ex:

```
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("role", "Admin");
props.put("externalId", "2ew1Q");
props.put("Property", "internal");
props.put("Execution", "internal");
```

My expected output should be:

```
<role>Admin</role>
<externalId>2ew1Q</externalId>
<Property>internal</Property>
<Execution>internal</Execution>
```

But instead of it, I'm getting

```
<entry string="role">Admin</entry>
<entry string="Execution">internal</entry>
<entry string="externalId">2ew1Q</entry>
<entry string="Property">internal</entry>
```

I have to do it with Simple XML, and this is my code:

```
    @Root
    public class Data {
    
        @ElementMap(entry = "property", key = "key", attribute = true, inline = true)
        private Map<String, String> customProps;
    
        public Map<String, String> getData() {
            return customProps;
        }
    
        public void setData(Map<String, String> data) {
            this.customProps = data;
        }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put("role", "Admin");
        props.put("externalId", "2ew1Q");
        props.put("Property", "internal");
        props.put("Execution", "internal");


        Data customProps = new Data();
        customProps.setData(props);

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File result = new File("example.xml");
        serializer.write(customProps, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`@ElementMap(entry = "property", key = "key", attribute = false, inline = true)`

Comment: No, I already try it, but it doesn't work, the attribute = false converts the entry into a parent tag. just like this: <property>
         <key>role</key>
         <string>Admin</string>
      </property>
      <property>
         <key>Execution</key>
         <string>internal</string>
      </property>.....

Comment: Can you not just do:
`private String role; private String externalId;` etc and then set those variables to what you want. They'll then automatically be turned into the nodes

Comment: The problem is that those values come from a database, so not always it will be "role" it could come "transferId" or even "asd" (just kidding), so the idea is that whatever is the value in the database the map could take that value and map inside the XML.